# SQL How to insert/update/delete all at the same time based on parent to child relationship

Tags: sql, node.js, database, relationship, prisma

Currently, I'm using a Postgres database with two tables, a Parent `Store` table, and a Child table called `Product` that will store the products in the store. These tables have a one to many relationship.

Now, on the frontend, users are presented with all the products for a store, and they can create, update, or delete products. When they submit, the frontend will make a query to the backend with the id of the store and the data of all the products.

My question is this: What is the best way to update the database based on this new data? The data is sent to the backend in JSON form, and will look similar to this:

```json
{
    "store": {
        "id": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 23423
                "name": "Product 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 12312
                "name": "Product 2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The server will need to update the `Product` table based on this new information. In this case, I know I can use an `UPSERT` method, but I also need to delete products that are no longer used for the store. How can I do this?

Currently, my backend is in Node.js and uses Prisma as the database ORM, but I am open to using raw SQL queries as well.

Comment: In this case, how would you differentiate which product needs to be added/updated and which one needs to be deleted?